# Facing flash of images when my page loads

Tags: css

When two stylesheets have classes with same names, how does the style apply on the elements? Does it apply both the styles linearly and then render the final output or it applies the first style and the one with higher specificity replaces the first one (showing both outputs maybe too fast)?

Comment: The styles are read in order of appearance. For each element _all_ rules are interpreted first, then applied, so rules can overwrite each other without getting applied one after another. However it might be that other rules influence the element at a later point in time if necessary. For example when dynamic content comes into play or if the original dimensions of the images have to get adapted for the layout.

Comment: To find the cause I suggest you use your browsers development console and check two things: 1. network requests dome _after_ the initial page loading and 2. compare the _computed_ styles to those defined by the rules to see if there are differences.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However, I would also like to know if the behavior you specified could be browser version dependent ( I am using IE8 n IE11) or on client server model?